# Is ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) 2016 fully compatible with ADFS 2012?

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I have to implement ADFS authentication with a third party provider, but I need to know if ADFS 2016 is fully compatible with ADFS 2012.
My provider uses ADFS 2012, but it's about to migrate to 2016 and I need to know if my work is going to be incompatible, unusable or something like that after that migration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - compatible - they are both based on protocols and that doesn't change.